# Tried to run the make command but got this error instead

Tags: python

This version of C:\MinGW\bin\make.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Wog.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.

If I were you I'd do a clean reinstall of MinGW. If that doesn't work come back
and post the full traceback of the error.